# How can I comment or uncomment multiple lines in the built-in MobaXterm editor?

Tags: editor, mobaxterm, block-comments

I would like to block-comment in MobaTextEditor.

There doesn't seem to be any info on this online in any place so I'm wondering if anyone knows where I can find documentation on this or if they know from experience.

I tried adding a keystroke for `ecCommentBlock` but that doesn't work (the keystroke doesn't do anything).

[image: Options window with custom keystroke]

I'm not sure why but information on this editor seems to be elusive, on their website the entire blurb on it is "`MobaXterm includes everything you need to edit text files: vi on command line, nedit for a graphical editor or MobaTextEditor which is a light but powerful editor for developers with textdiff utilities.`"

Anyone have experience with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

- Select the code that you want to comment
- Right-click and then select according to the language format, i.e for python we comment by using #.
- You can choose for each language editor.
- Same for uncommenting
- A screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3duh.png) is also here.